# Nested Json Structure .NET

Tags: c#, .net, json, put

I would like to achieve the following JSON structure in my code for .NET but I cannot seem to create the array `[Attributes]` correctly from my database.

How do you best setup nested Json like this?

```
{
    "productid": 0,
    "active": true,
    "activepos": true,
    "title": "Test",
    "sku": "7777766666",
    "deliverystatus": "",
    "moneyprice": "1590.00",
    "moneypriceorg": "0.00",
    "moneypricein": "8.00",
    "moneyofferprice": "0.00",
    "friendly": "This is Friendly",
    "barcode": "",
    "attributes": [ "Casual", "Green" ]
}
```

Here is my class, should I have a separate class for this? And how can I join classes to build nested JSON?

```
public class ProductSQL
{
        public string sku { get; set; } 
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string moneypricein { get; set; }
        public string moneyprice { get; set; }
        public string ean { get; set; }
        public string [] attributes { get; set; }
}
```

In my SQL database, I have five columns `attribute 1, attribute 2, attribute 3, attribute 4, attribute 5`.

I am assuming a separate class for attributes with five columns that then should be concatenated?

Any advise in best practise JSON building would be appreciated. This is a put request.

Comment: "In my SQL database, I have five columns" - bad idead like that pop up all the time. Separate table. Seriously, it is called RELATIONAL database, not "one file databae". Use a relation here, or you WILL pay for it. Comes up every other week and here when people get into problems with their non relational data structure.

Comment: I am aware of that, but thinking how should it be parsed to a json object as one row, that is my problem here. i can have all the relations in the world. but i cannot parse two rows of the same product in .net. If you have any experience with json and using data from sql i would much appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice (my opinion only) would be to have all the fields that you have in your database (all fields that you are `SELECT`ing, that is), on your C# class instead of collecting them into an array.

Thing with SQL DB is, a row represents a **unit of data**. If you need to store a list or an array of some data related to that unit, you must use a **separate table** for this.

So, depending on the contextual meaning of your `attribute1`, `attribute2` fields, you should either

- Create another table (to store these attributes) with a foreign key in the first table, or,
- If all of the attributes are fixed and indeed belong to each "unit" and they have a simple one-column representation (or complex serializable), then your approach might suffice.

But, judging by how you didn't name any of your attributes, I suspect the second option, well, is not an option for you.

it still depends on the meaning of those attributes, but if you are naming them `...1`, `...2`, and so on, it might be a sign of a **bad design**.

If you are trying to collect columns of a row into an array, it is a strong sign of a **bad design**.

When you encounter bad design signs, well, the best you should do is to rethink logically what it is that you want.

Comment: good advice, i will model relationally and then try to rethink the design of how to structure the nested JSON query correctly. Thanks for the support here.

Comment: @Bradley the JSON pretty much should be structured as your data already is/willbe in the database